# Why does ASP.NET MVC rename controllers that start with a number?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried to create a Controller class with the name `1BigController`, but MVC won't let me do that. It changes the controller name to `_BigController`.

Why can't I start a controller name with a number?

Comment: Please, tag questions relating to ASP.NET with tag "asp.net", ".net" etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is a convention of all C# classes, not just MVC. You can find more in the [C# Language Specification (item 2.4.2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx)

Here's a similar question regarding variable names and numeric vals

[Why can't variable names start with numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you can't have class names that start with a number. I used to program PLC's and the software we used wouldn't allow us to start any tag names with a number. I don't know why we couldn't other then that was the rule.

Answer (score 0):

MVC uses a convention approach to type resolution. A controller name such as "Big" will cause MVC to search for a `BigController`. Likewise, if it was not sanitised as "_" and instead was "1Big", MVC would attempt to find a type called `1BigController`. Type names cannot start with numbers, so it gets sanitised for you.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names have to start with a letter or underscore. The remaining characters can be letters, underscores, or digits. I am not sure why this is the convention, but it has been for a long time.