# Is there any language that allows spaces in its variable names

Tags: whitespace, esoteric-languages

Is there (or was there ever) any non-trivial language that allows spaces in its variable names?

I am aware of the language [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29), but I'm interested in a language that was actually used for something besides demonstration.

I ask this out of pure curiosity.

Comment: weird question... well PHP allows it, in an obscure way `        $foobar = "bar foo";
        ${$foobar} = "foo bar";
        var_dump(get_defined_vars(${$foobar}));`

Comment: Windows `set` command considers spaces before `=` in the variable name. So `set var =` will create a variable called `%var %` but `set var=` will create a variable called `%var%`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a way, yes. Several languages's variable names are really just keys to a higher-level object. Both Coldfusion and Javascript come to mind. In Javascript, you can write `foo=bar`, but what you've really said is:

```
window['foo'] = bar;
```

You could just as easily write

```
window['i haz a name'] = bar;
```

The various scopes in Coldfusion can also be treated as either a (dict|hash|associative array) or a name.

Of course, once you've created a name with whitespace, it's harder to access without using the hash lookup syntax.

Comment: Thanks kojiro, I guess this an SQL is as close as any language comes, you get the point because you were first.

Answer (score 2):

TSQL will allow you to use whitespace in table and column names aslong as you have it between square braces `[ ]`

Theres a fantastic article on just what sql will let you get away with here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/philfactor/archive/2009/08/14/evil-code.aspx