# Why can't variable names have spaces in them?

Tags: variables, programming-languages, language-design, variable-names

Related: [Why can't variable names start with numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/342152/1907098)

Is there a technical reason why spaces aren't allowed in variable names or is it down to convention?

For example, what's stopping us from doing something like this?:

```
average score = sum of scores / number of scores
```

The only issue that comes to mind is keywords, but one could simply restrict the use of them in a variable name, and the lexer would be able to distinguish between part of a variable and a keyword.

Comment: Not all languages require parentheses for function calls so `average score` looks like `average(score)` in some languages.

Comment: @TedHopp: That is asking for a language with the feature. This is asking for a technical explanation of why the feature is not common. I think it might be better suited to Programmers.

Comment: @JonPurdy should I move this over to Programmers then?

Comment: @Volatility: You can flag it and ask for a moderator to migrate/merge it. I just realised that [it has been asked on Programmers before](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/145751/2107), and I even answered that question! :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There’s no *fundamental* reason, apart from the decisions of language designers and a history of single-token identifiers. Some languages in fact do allow multi-token identifiers: MultiMedia Fusion’s expression language, some Mac spreadsheet/notebook software whose name escapes me, and I’m sure of others. There are several considerations that make the problem nontrivial, though.

Presuming the language is free-form, you need a canonical representation, so that an identifier like `account name` is treated the same regardless of whitespace. A compiler would probably need to use some mangling convention to please a linker. Then you have to consider the effect of that on foreign exports—why C++ has the `extern "C"` linkage specifier to disable mangling.

Keywords are an issue, as you have seen. Most C-family languages have a lexical class of keywords distinct from identifiers, which are not context-sensitive. You cannot name a variable `class` in C++. This can be solved by disallowing keywords in multi-token identifiers:

```
if account age < 13 then child account = true;
```

Here, `if` and `then` cannot be part of an identifier, so there is no ambiguity with `account age` and `child account`. Alternatively, you can require punctuation everywhere:

```
if (account age < 13) {
  child account = true;
}
```

The last option is to make keywords pervasively context-sensitive, leading to such monstrosities as:

```
IF IF = THEN THEN ELSE = THEN ELSE THEN = ELSE
```

The biggest issue is that juxtaposition is an extremely powerful syntactic construct, and you don’t want to occupy it lightly. Allowing multi-token identifiers prevents using juxtaposition for another purpose, such as function application or composition. Far better, I think, just to allow most *nonwhitespace* characters and thereby permit such identifiers as `canonical-venomous-frobnicator`. Still plenty readable but with fewer opportunities for ambiguity.

Comment: Oh well, looks like this isn't going to be migrated. But thanks for the great answer, especially the part about juxtaposition. Having coming from a mainly Python background, it didn't come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is bacause the designers of the language have followed this convention.

I have searched on Google and found that while naming a variable this is a rule which is followed while naming a variable.

Some links are given below:-

- [SPSS notes](http://webservices.itcs.umich.edu/mediawiki/qualtrics/index.php/SPSS_notes)

> The following rules apply to variable names:
>
> - Variable names cannot contain spaces.

- [C Programming/Variables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Variables)
- [Variable names by IBM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/dataedit_variable_names.htm)
- [Java Variable Naming convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal
> identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
> digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the
> underscore character "*". The convention, however, is to always begin
> your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "*". Additionally, the
> dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may
> find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the
> dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A
> similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's
> technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this
> practice is discouraged. **White space is not permitted.**

- [Wiki for Naming Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29)

In all of the above links you will find that the designers have followed this naming convention for naming the variable.

Also check [Is there any language that allows spaces in its variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141160/is-there-any-language-that-allows-spaces-in-its-variable-names)

Answer (score 0):

This is forced from language designing.
Compiler needs to find out the meaning of words.
Compiler works on a "State Machine" method, and it needs to distinguish key words.
Maybe placing variable names in "[" and "]" give us some solution(like SQL).
But it will be harder to use it in coding...