# Javascript : var 3po = true;?

Tags: javascript

I read some where else that following is illegal

```
var 3po = true;
```

but

```
var highNoon = false;
```

is legal.

Could someone explain what is all this means? Why the first statement is illegal while the second is legal?

Comment: see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean legal as in Syntax-wise?

The first example will give you a SyntaxError, the reason is that variables should not begin with a number.

Answer (score 7):

An identifier cannot start with a number as the ECMAScript grammar explains:

```
Identifier :: 
    IdentifierName but not ReservedWord 

IdentifierName :: 
    IdentifierStart 
    IdentifierName IdentifierPart 

IdentifierStart :: 
    UnicodeLetter 
    $ 
    _ 
    \ UnicodeEscapeSequence 

IdentifierPart :: 
    IdentifierStart 
    UnicodeCombiningMark 
    UnicodeDigit 
    UnicodeConnectorPunctuation 
    <ZWNJ> 
    <ZWJ>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the [EcmaScript documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf), page 15.

```
IdentifierName ::
    IdentifierStart
    IdentifierName IdentifierPart

IdentifierStart ::
    UnicodeLetter
    $
    _
    \ UnicodeEscapeSequence
```

So, the identifier could start from the letter, $, _ or unicode escape sequence, not the digit.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that you meant "Why variables should not begin with a number?"

Just guesing...