# Why is this allowed in PHP?

Tags: php

Why doesn't PHP throw an error on line 7?

https://ideone.com/DHMLCY

```
<?php

class Test {
    public function __construct(){

        $name = 123;
        $this->$name = 'Test';
        var_dump($this->$name);


        $this->123 = 'Test2';
        var_dump($this->123);

    }
}

$test = new Test();
var_dump($test);
```

I always thought, that class fields couldn't start with numbers. But that doesn't seem to be the case if the number is in a variable.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10333016/3933332

Comment: Line 7 of the code in the question is blank btw

Comment: I don't believe it even gets to execute line 7.... parse error triggers first while it's parsing/compiling

Comment: However, defining properties dynamically bypasses that rule.... and necessarily so, for some of the XML that I've seen (with numeric names for elements) when converting to SimpleXML

Comment: A good read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15427553/3000179

Comment: Interesting question! I din't expect this either. Shud b called as a bug rathr than feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is because of the dynamic nature of PHP variables.

If you read the vardump of the defined class property:

```
 object(Test)#1 (1) { ["123"]=> string(4) "Test" }
```

You can see its (index is) a string, not a integer as you're expecting it to be

Comment: So behind the scenes it gets converted to a string? That's good to know!