# how to create array inside for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create 10 arrays inside a `for` loop, using the names 1, 2, 3, ..., 10 for the arrays.

I tried like this, but it's not working:

```
int n = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    String [] i = new String[];
}
```

Comment: What is your intent for doing this?

Comment: It's not working since it is not allowed in java language.

Comment: downvoter: what's wrong with the question?

Comment: People don't understand down-vote ettiquette. Just because you think a question is "stupid" to you doesn't mean its a poor quality question.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers

Comment: I've fixed a misprint: replaced o as the starting value of `i` with 0. And I agree, this is not a bad question.

Comment: i am trying to write a program asked by tcs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning variables with dynamic names in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

```
int n = 10;
int m = 5;

String[][] arrayOfArrays = new String[n][];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    arrayOfArrays[i] = new String[m];
}
```

Comment: ok, if i do like this how to get the value of 2nd index of array name 2

Comment: @Prasanth index start from 0, 2nd index is [1], so `arrayOfArrays[1]`

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to map number with array

```
Map<Integer,String[]> map = new HashMap<>(10);
for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
{
   map.put(i,new String[10]);
}
```

Comment: please fix that `o` from the OPs code and make it a `0` its bothering me.

Comment: He didn't ask for a map

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer He asked for how to dynamically name variables based on the value of that iterator, which isn't supported.  A map is an appropriate solution.

Comment: @Youngistan I disagree. This is just about the only way to generate a bunch of anonymous variables. You either have to name them (obviously the OP can't or doesn't want to) or store them in a list or map and access their index.

Comment: ok, if i do like this how to get the value of 2nd index of array name 2

Comment: @Prasanth String val = map.get(2)[1]

Comment: @leigero then why to use map simply go with Set,List then there is so many solutions

Comment: @Youngistan what collection you use is irrelevant. The fact of the matter is that he needs to store these in some sort of collection and they can't be created dynamically like he tried. Therefore, this is very much a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can't declare a variable with leading numbers.

Comment: This is not the issue at all. While what you say it true, a variable cannot be used as a variable name in Java - it is simply not supported by the language.

Comment: @BoristheSpider OP claimed that he wanted arrays with names 1,2 and 3, so I think this answer is more related than the fact that a variable cannot be used as a variable name in Java

Comment: @McKevin I think what Boris is trying to say... is that while your statement is true, its not an answer to this question, and has little at all to do with the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

In you code `i` is already defined within the scope of the `for` loop.
Also as soon as you exit the loop, the created variables will be out of scope.

Furthermore, variables beginning with an Integer are invalid in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList` for creating an array of array, else go for a 2D `String` array.

```
ArrayList<String[]> x = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    int n =10;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        x.add(new String[5]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use a 2D array which might offers what you need.

Read this [Syntax for creating a two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/creating-two-dimensional-array)

```
String [][] test = new String [10][10];
```

It is as if the first [] can be your 'i' like what you required, and the 2nd [] can be what you need to store the variable. It is normally use for cases like if you need an "array of array", meaning 100x array.