# Is there a reason why CSS doesn't support ids and classes, starting from numbers?

Tags: css

I noticed that css properties aren't applied if id or class starts from number. For example, none of following will work:

```
.1ww{
    /* some properties here */
}
```

and

```
.1{
    /* some properties here */
}
```

and

```
#1{
    /* some properties here */
}
```

and

```
#1ww{
    /* some properties here */
}
```

Why doesn't CSS support ids or class names, starting from numbers? (Javascript, for example, works with numeric ids and classes)

Comment: Since you have accepted an answer that does not address the “why” question, it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, the specification states that classes starting with a number will be interpreted as a dimension [[1](http://plnkr.co/edit/024EEM1FRdFqqmwHVbjJ?p=preview)]:

> CSS2 parses a number immediately followed by an identifier as a DIMENSION token (i.e., an unknown unit), CSS1 parsed it as a number and an identifier. That means that in CSS1, the declaration 'font: 10pt/1.2serif' was correct, as was 'font: 10pt/12pt serif'; in CSS2, a space is required before "serif". (Some UAs accepted the first example, but not the second.)

and since we don't know which dimensions will be introduced in the future, dimensions that do not exist in CSS are parsed as unknown dimensions:

> In CSS1, a class name could start with a digit (".55ft"), unless it was a dimension (".55in"). In CSS2, such classes are parsed as unknown dimensions (**to allow for future additions of new units**). To make ".55ft" a valid class, CSS2 requires the first digit to be escaped (".\35 5ft")

You can use class starting with numbers by escaping the first digit, which is valid according to the W3C CSS validator. check out the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/024EEM1FRdFqqmwHVbjJ?p=preview).

[[1](http://plnkr.co/edit/024EEM1FRdFqqmwHVbjJ?p=preview)] Appendix G. Grammar of CSS 2.1

Comment: The first quotation is not relevant here. The second one may explain the restriction on class selectors. For ID selectors, it might be a matter of analogy, or it might depend on the original HTML definition of `id` selectors, which required the value to start with a letter.

Comment: the first quotation is of course relevant. it states that a number immediately followed by an identifier will be parsed as a dimension token (e.g., .1ww = 1 x unit 'ww'), and to allow for future additions unknown units do also result in a dimension token. id selectors starting with a number conflicts with a HEX color token (e.g., #1ff <- id selector or HEX color?) please refer to [Lexical Scanner](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner)

Answer (score 8):

IDs and classes must be valid identifiers.

Identifiers are listed like so in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/grammar.html):

```
ident       -?{nmstart}{nmchar}*
```

So an optional `-` sign, followed by `nmstart`, followed by any number of `nmchar`s.

The one we're interested in is `nmstart`, but I'll also list `nmchar`:

```
nmstart     [_a-z]|{nonascii}|{escape}
nmchar      [_a-z0-9-]|{nonascii}|{escape}
```

And just for completeness:

```
nonascii    [\240-\377]
escape      {unicode}|\\[^\r\n\f0-9a-f]
unicode     \\{h}{1,6}(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?
```

Okay, so with all that out of the way, *notice how `nmstart` does **not** include `0-9` or `-`*. This means that IDs and classes *cannot* start with a number according to the CSS specification. In fact, they can't even start with `-1`. Or two hyphens.

This is why they are not recognised in your code.

Comment: This does not answer the question “Why doesn't CSS support ids or class names, starting from numbers?” It just explains in detailt that it does not, except that it does not explain how the escapes work.

Comment: Really, Niet the Dark Absol, it says that CSS doesn't support per docs, but could you explain why? You confused me :D

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Could you explain me why or you don't know?

Comment: @nicael If you want more on the why, see reagten's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Although it is not a good convention to start Id and class names with a number you can access these elements from within your css by making use of the following syntax

```
[class="1ww"] 
{
    /* some properties here */
}
```

or

```
[id="1"]
{
    /* some properties here */
}
```

Comment: It's interesting to note that the quotes around "match by attribute value" values are often optional. But not here, for the exact same reason as `#1` not being allowed in the first place :D

Answer (score 1):

It is a rule of CSS. [Here is the link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can 
>       contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, 
>       plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, 
>       two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [HTML5.1 Nightly from 5 October 2014](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute), they agree that there is no reason the ID shouldn't be able to start with a number:

> **Note:** There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in
>   particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start
>   with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.

If you must use a number at the start of an ID, you could (as mentioned in [the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453575/1028949)) use the attribute selector, or [you could escape the number](https://mothereff.in/css-escapes).

```
#\31 ww
{
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmLLdw1z/)

You can achieve it with CSS but differently

**HTML**

```
<div id="1">Some Id with Number</div>
```

**CSS**

```
[id='1']
{
    font-size: 60px;
    color: red;
}
```

**But**

```
#1 /*Not gonna work*/
{
    font-size: 60px;
    color: red;
}
```

Similarly for Class;

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xh5myz73/)**

**CSS**

```
[class="1"]
{
    font-size: 100px;
    color: red;
}
```

**Is there a reason why CSS doesn't support ids and classes, starting from numbers?**
One of the main reason for it is; it has no semantic meanings. e.g.

```
<div id="1" class="2"></div> /*has no semantic meanings*/
```

It can be fixed as;

```
<div id="header" class="top-spacing"></div>
```

**[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/)**

Comment: Good, but could you answer my question?

Comment: @nicael I have updated the answer. One of the key aspect in html is SEO. So markup should be semantic. #s are poor have poor or no semantic meanings therefore its one the key reason that they weren't supported.

Answer (score 1):

To plagiarise an answer to a similar question I read a long time ago on here: It's convention carried over from other older languages.

In the past, languages such as FORTRAN and BASIC didn't require the use of spaces so something like this:

```
10 A1 = 10
```

Would be identical to this:

```
10A1=10
```

The problem  is, things like this would be very difficult to understand:

```
111A=10
```

As it could be interpreted as either:

```
11 1A = 10
```

or:

```
111 A = 10
```

etc.

As a result, starting variables with a number was made illegal. This is a convention that has persisted and is still present in most languages today, CSS included.

EDIT: [found the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that there is a CSS specific reason. This is an old standard for programming languages. Language tokenizers can be faster/simplier, if the first character can determine that the whole token is a number or an identifier (a token preceded by a numeric character must be a numeric literal).

```
var x = 10e4; // is this a variable?
```