# Weird CSS Selector - Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

I have come across a weird selector that is working fine however I don't understand how it is working. All I did was perform a "Copy Selector" using chrome debugging options and it provided me with the selector given below. Could you let me know what does that mean? Its something that I haven't come across.

**The HTML markup is:**

```
<ul id="633456">
<li>
<a>A link</a>
<div>
...
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS Selector from Chrome debugging tools:**

```
#\36 33456 > li > div { /* Not sure what #\36 33456 means */
...
}
```

Please let me know how this works.
I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WKSkC/3/) as well.

Cheers.

Comment: It's escaping since IDs shouldn't start with numbers.

Comment: What about `33456`, @Paulie_D?

Comment: What about 33456? Using just that? Why is there a space and also why does it have a 3 after the backslash?

Comment: I know this is a duplicate..just trying to find it.

Comment: [Btw, related question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453303/is-there-a-reason-why-css-doesnt-support-ids-and-classes-starting-from-numbers).

Comment: Yes...it is...now - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672903/can-i-have-a-div-with-id-as-number/5672936#5672936  CSS however doesn't support it so they have to be escaped.

Comment: That's the one I was looking for...thanks.

Comment: Don't like the idea that you must escape the CSS selector if it starts with a number, IMHO. Cheers

Comment: Don't like the idea either but I think that's how the selector is for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once Paulie_D told me its to do with escaping the ID as it cannot start with a number, a bit of googling gave me the right answer.

https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Which is why the ID: 633456 is written as: **#\36 33456**

Thanks.

Comment: Please close-vote as duplicate instead of providing yet another answer to the same question.