# Structure array inside a structure array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a structure array `c` as below:

```
       c(i).j.k = something;
```

I want to have a structure array inside a structure array, so `c` has two labels, `i` and `j`, however I am having difficulty in doing this and keep getting an error:

```
Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

Any help on how to do this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip! I'm more into maths than programming, so indices are automatically i j and k for me!

Comment: what is the error you are getting? what have you tried?

Comment: Have added the error to the post, I just get unexpected matlab expression

Comment: I have just tried that, unfortunately it did not make a difference

Comment: i, and j are both integers and k is a string for me at the moment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nothing looks suspicious thus far, maybe looking at the code where you are generating `i`, `j` and `k` might help solve the issue.

Comment: @Divakar I've added the full code to the post, thanks again, this is much appreciated

Comment: It may seem strange that I just have a 1 there at the moment, however I need c to be in this form for another function I am using elsewhere

Comment: @Divakar See the above comment, sorry I posted that quickly!

Comment: That's done it! Thank you. If you want to make it into an answer I can accept it

Comment: Ok, so I think the way these labels, which are technically called as the fieldnames, mustn't have names starting with numerals, like `1` in your case. You can do `L1` or `L2`, etc. though, but not `1L` or `2L`. It's the same when you try to name variable starting with numerals, won't work.

Comment: Sorry I spoke too soon on that, see my comment just above this one.

Comment: and seems like its a well-discussed topic with programming in general - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers