# python string formatting using .format and variable

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, syntax-error, string.format

```
s1 = "cats"

print "are 10 cats {}" .format(s1*10) 
print "are 10 cats {10cats}" .format(10cats=s1*10)
```

First `print` works, second I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Why?

Comment: Or unpack a dictionary `"..."..format(**{"10cats": s1*10})`

Comment: It's kind of weird to have numbers in your variable names at all. What if your boss comes in tomorrow and says "good job on the cat project, but we need to increase max cat-capacity from 10 to 20". Now you have to replace your `_10cats` variable everywhere with `_20cats`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable names in python (and many other languages) [cannot start with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers). If you used a legal variable name, the second would work fine.

```
>>> s1 = "cats"
>>> print("are 10 cats {cats}" .format(cats=s1*10))
are 10 cats catscatscatscatscatscatscatscatscatscats
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated already, variable names in Python cannot start with numbers.  Additionally, there are other characters that cannot be used in variable names in Python.

http://www.pasteur.fr/formation/infobio/python/ch02s03.html