# Why is this polynomial function throwing a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, polynomial-math

I am trying to write a basic algorithm to evaluate a fourth order polynomial using Python. The code is below, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I came up with this code and I am not sure if it is enough to do the trick:

```
x = int(raw_input(":"))
def eval_poly(x):
    if abs(x) > 0:
        return 35x**4-17x**3+5x**2+41x-29
print eval_poly(x)
```

The error that I get says that `35x**4` is an invalid syntax and the polynomial that I am trying to evaluate is as follows:

```
35x^4 - 17x^3 + 5x^2 + 41x -29
```

Comment: Why do you need the `if abs(x) > 0` line? The function returns `None` if you feed in x=0, but it’s valid to evaluate the polynomial at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although we write (35 *x*) in mathematics to implicitly mean (35 * *x*), the Python interpreter can’t work this out. You need to tell it `35 * (x ** 4)` explicitly.

So you modify the function to include

```
return 35 * (x ** 4) - 17 * (x ** 3) + 5 * (x ** 2) + 41 * x - 29
```

(The parentheses aren’t strictly necessary, because Python will get the right order of operations without them, but I think they aid readability.)

---

It’s worth saying: the error gets thrown when Python tries to evaluate the expression `35x`, but it doesn’t know how to interpret this. It starts with a digit, hence not a variable ([variables have to start with a non-digit character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/342152/1558022)), but contains an alphabet character, hence not a number. It’s not just that it doesn’t know what this expression means, it’s that `35x` is impossible for Python to parse.

Comment: appreciate the help. didnt think about it like that at all

Answer (score 1):

```
35*(x**4) - 17*(x**3) + 5*(x**2) + 41*x - 29
```

Answer (score 0):

You left the multiplication:

```
35*x**4-17*x**3+5*x**2+41*x-29
```

Comment: one thing i hate about obvious mistakes, they are obvious. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly perform multiplication as below. ie. 7x becomes 7*x.

Otherwise it looks good...

```
x = int(raw_input(":"))
def eval_poly(x):
    if abs(x) > 0:
        return 35*x**4-17*x**3+5*x**2+41*x-29
print eval_poly(x)
```