# Why angular is behaving unexpected with different strings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have started learning angular JS. I confused with very basic.

**What I am doing**: I am playing with 2 string `postNumber123` and `123preNumber`.
angular showing error for string start with number, and ignoring if string start with characters. 
I just wanted to know in deep what is the resone behaind it? or I am missing something?

**Angular ignoring this error:**

```
<div ng-app="" >
     <div> Testing : {{ postNumber123 }} </div>  <!-- ignoring error --> 
    <div>After execution : {{ 3+4 }} </div>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" >
    
    <!-- <div> Testing : {{ 123preNumber }} </div> --> <!-- showing error -->
    
     <div> Testing : {{ postNumber123 }} </div>  <!-- ignoring error --> 
    
    <div>After execution : {{ 3+4 }} </div>
    
</div>
```

**Showing error for this:**

```
<div ng-app="" >
    <div> Testing : {{ 123preNumber }} </div> <!-- showing error -->
    <div>After execution : {{ 3+4 }} </div>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" >
        <div> Testing : {{ 123preNumber }} </div> <!-- showing error -->
        
        <!-- <div> Testing : {{ postNumber123 }} </div> --> <!-- ignoring error --> 
        
        <div>After execution : {{ 3+4 }} </div>
        
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`123preNumber` is not a valid variable because it starts with a number, use `postNumber123` instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers) for more details why.

Comment: Thanks I got it, It means that the angular find the variable, in case variable does not defind, angular ignore it and execute next. In my case angular directly pointing this is not valid js variable.

Answer (score 3):

`123preNumber` isn't a valid JS expression.

`postNumber123` is a valid JS variable name.

Answer (score 0):

variable name always start from **all alphabetic, _,  $** in mostly computer language and same validation apply with AngularJS.
so make sure when declare any variable.