# In python, is there any way of creating a variable that has the name of a value of another variable?

Tags: python, variables

As an example:
diameter = 7

next is where I would want to give the a value a variable name of 7

7 = 21

Comment: Are you trying to make `7` equal to `21`? Reminds me of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9182/311398) where Jon makes 3 equal to 1.

Comment: `7` is not a valid variable name

Comment: you can't make `7` the name of a variable

Comment: Values in Python don't have names; namespaces hold names (which are, in general, just strings that are permitted names) and refer to objects. Since 7 is an integer literal in the language, it will never reach a name lookup.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it by modifying [**locals()**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals):

```
my_var = 'vla'
locals()[locals()['my_var']] = 'some_value'
# or use setdefault if you don't wan't to override variable if it already exist
locals().setdefault(locals()['my_var'], 'some_value')
print vla
# some_value
```

**NOTE:** value of `my_var` should be a **valid python variable name**. Which is the uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the 
underscore _ and, except for the first character, the digits 0 through 9 ( shortly use pattern **/[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*/i** as **@hjpotter** suggested).

**For your case** you have to add some prefix before creating new variable from value, because your value is invalid variable name, see code below:

```
diameter = 7
# diameter value is invalid name for our new variable,
# let's add `_` prefix to value to  be sure name is valid:
locals()['_' + str(locals()['my_var'])] = 'some_value'
# Note that i've applied str function to value of diameter variable
# to avoid TypeError (cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects)
```

Comment: just use the pattern: `/[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*/i`

Answer (score 1):

No. If you are attempting to assign a value to a numeral, that is not valid. Variable names *must*:

- Start with either a letter *or* an underscore like:

  ```
  _varname 
  varname
  ```
- Numerals may exist in the remainder of the variable name like:

  ```
  _varname1
  varname1
  ```

As a side note, variables are case sensitive too. Thus `varname` and `Varname` are two different variables.

A bit more detail can be found in this (non-python specific) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers) about why variables can't start with a number.