# Can variable names in Python start with an integer?

Tags: python, variable-names

This is somewhat academic, but nevertheless.

Python syntax forbids starting a variable name with a number, but this can be sidestepped like so:

```py
>>> globals()['1a'] = 1
>>> globals()['1a']
1
```

Likewise for `locals()`.

Does that mean that Python actually allows it, and that it's just not very visible?

#### Edit:

My question is not whether it is allowed; I am aware that it is formally not allowed in Python. The question is why can I work around it by addressing `globals()` directly, and if that breaks certain rules or guidelines, or if it has a good reason/application to allow that.

Comment: The parser disallows it, but you can do it by hijacking `globals()`. But you're not really intended to do that.

Comment: You can't use it as a variable later... so it isn't really a variable, even though it is in the same namespace.

Comment: Your answer (duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't variable names start with numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers)

Comment: @MichaelMMeskhi, not a dup, IMO. OP actually asks if his hack is sane, not about parsing rules.

Comment: @Kay Hmmm, you are right. I didn't get OP's initial intentions

Comment: @steffan Modifying `locals` doesn't work [https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals] so you can only do this trick in `globals`

Comment: @DavidW I just tried it... it works in Python 3.6.0 and 2.7.13

Comment: @steffen So it looks like you're right in this case... Generally though messing with locals is a disaster: e.g. `def f(): locals()['a'] = 1; print(a)` (raises an error) or even `def f(): a=0; locals()['a']=1; print(a)` (prints 0)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Python parser forbids naming variables that way, for the sake of parsing numbers and variables separately, as naming a variable `1e1` would create a chaos - is it the number `10.0` or the variable `1e1`?

*"Python, please output for me `1e1`!" - "Why is it 10.0? I stored 100 over there!"*

*But* the variables are actually stored in a way that allows binding a string that starts with a number to a value, because that feature is no harm in hashing maps of any kind, and so using this "trick" you can achieve your wanted numeral-prefixed-name variable without hurting the parser severability.

I would say that technically, naming variables in that manner is **not a violation** to python guidelines, but it is highly discouraged, and as a rule unnecessary. Using `globals` for injecting variables is known as a very **bad practice** and this case should not be an outstanding.

---

Of course, python could have used an encloser to numerals like strings, say `*123*`, but I believe the intent of inventing python was to make programming easier, not stretching the limits of variable naming space.

---

Practically speaking, if you *must* use number-headed names you better do it with your own dictionary, rather than `globals`:

```
>>> number_headed_vars = {'1a': 100}
>>> number_headed_vars['1a']
100
```

That way you can create your own variables system - and avoid abusing `globals()`.

Comment: I suspect this was not implemented more because it would cause ambiguity in the grammar of the old parser (<=3.8). I believe it *could* be implemented with the new PEG parser (>=3.9) but I doubt the core-devs would deem it a necessary addition and therefore would vote against any PEP proposing this.

Answer (score 8):

This is what you can and can't do with that `1a` in globals. You can't really use it in a variable, unless you use all of it's definition in globals (I mean accessing that dictionary), which makes it very uncomfortable for usage (another reason for not doing that).

Basically, `1a` is not a real variable as `a1` , as shown in the following output:

```
>>> globals()['1a'] = 1
>>> globals()['1a']
1

>>> a = 1a
File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = 1a
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> a = globals()['1a']
>>> a
1

>>> globals()['a1'] = 5
>>> a = a1
>>> a
5
```

Comment: Hi, came back to this question because of upvotes wave, and seen the sentence `"1a is not a real variable."`. While this makes sense, it isn't true. The problem isn't that `1a` isn't a "real" variable. The reason you can't use it in your code is because the parser **can not tokenize `1a` as a variable** (if it could, it would have worked perfectly, since is it stored normally in the `globals`). The rest is all good.