# Calling multiple functions stored in a different .py file (which names start with numbers)

Tags: python, import

I try to import `negated` from `03_a_ImportPredefinedWordLists.py` (where `negated` along with some other functions is stored). I tried what is suggested in [this post](http://ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477823/calling-a-function-in-a-separate-file-in-python)

```
from 03_a_ImportPredefinedWordLists import negated
```

Python complains about syntax error because the `.py` starts with a number.

```
 File "<ipython-input-12-fc574baf5a3f>", line 1
    from 03_a_ImportPredefinedWordLists import negated
           ^
 SyntaxError: invalid token
```

If I rename the `.py` file to `ImportPredefinedWordLists`, it works fine. Given there are many `.py` files, I numbered them, to keep track. I would not like to change that unless I have to. Is there a "workaround". I tried to escape using `\` but could not get it working

Comment: Having a file name starting with a number is asking for trouble... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number

Comment: Actually come from the fact that variable names should not start with a number https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962391/variable-names-in-python-cannot-start-with-a-number-or-can-they

Comment: after reading some more, I agree. one can easily circumven the problem by adding some letter before all numbers, preserving the order and readability of the file names. I will leave the question online and accept the answer that best fits the original task or importing a function from a file starting with a number, in case anyone else faces the same issues and cannot (for some reason) rename the files