# convert json to object in python with numbers as key

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm new in python, I have a json with int as key values such as this:

```
"data": {
        "1": {
            "b": 1
} 
}
```

I want to cast it to object:

```
x = json.loads(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True), object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
```

now I want to access to b . how should I do that . this code returns error:

x.1.b

Comment: Maybe `getattr(x, 1).b`

Comment: this error happens: TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not just use a regular dict (which by the way, *is an object*)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, variables are not allowed to start with a number.

```py
getattr(x, "1").b
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr

Related post:
[Can variable names in Python start with an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962391/can-variable-names-in-python-start-with-an-integer)

Comment: this error happens: TypeError: 'types.SimpleNamespace' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I didn't see you were trying to convert it to `types.SimpleNamespace`. Variables are not allowed to start with a number. Although you can still access the attributes by doing: `getattr(x, "1")`. Although, I would recommend keeping the json as a dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to use your `dict` directly.

```py
data = {
    "1": {"b": 1} 
}

some_value = data["1"]["b"]
```

If you want to use `SimpleNamespace` you need to replace `1` with something like `_1` to be able to use something like `x._1.b` because `x.1.b` raises a syntax error.

This can be done by recursively converting your dict to a `SimpleNamespace` object and inserting `_` in all keys starting with a number.

```py
def dict_to_namespace(d):
    return SimpleNamespace(
        **{
            (f"_{k}" if k[0].isdecimal() else k): (
                dict_to_namespace(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v
            )
            for k, v in d.items()
        }
    )

x = dict_to_namespace(data)
some_value = x._1.b
```

Note: this will lead to errors if your dict/json keys contain special characters (spaces, dashes etc.)

Comment: thanks. it is a good practice. but i'm looking for if there is any way to cast to object

Comment: @alikamrani in fact, a `dict` is an object, because pretty much everything in python is an object.

Comment: @alikamrani a dict *is an object*.