# Having problems with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having problems with JQuery.
The thing is that i want the height of a (div) `header` as `margin-top` of a `div` which its class is "content", because otherwise, the div appears under the header.

Here you have the code:

**Part of the HTML**

```
<head>
    /*whatever it's inside*/
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var 1 = $(".header").height() + "px");
        $(".content").css ('margin-top', 1);
    });
    </script>
<body>

    <div class="header">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><a href="#">Web</a></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">

        <div class="content">


    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.
</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Part of CSS**

```
 body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    background: #6396bc;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
.content {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

I just put what is useful.

You have the JS in the **HTML**.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var 1 =` a number cannot be a variable [Variable name in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names). `$(".header").height() + "px")` the last `)` is a syntax error.

Comment: Try simply `$(".content").css('margin-top', $(".header").height());`

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the javascript var 1 is incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers for more detaiils, but basiclly is NOT START VARIABLES WITH NUMBERS.

Comment: Please update the question title to be more specific.

Comment: Problem solved, I did what "Sahil" told, I just changed the 1 for an "x".

Comment: Pete, I know, I just wanted to put that in there so you knew that there was much stuff.

Comment: Just post here to answer you : nope & nope, I use an IDE since the beginningI started Java about 5 years ago, when there is an error I just learn the rule or get detail on internet, take a look at my SO profile if you think I don't learn Java. The IDE just help you going faster to learn, it tells you the error, then you turn to understand it, without IDE you stay stuck so much time just to know the error :D

Comment: @azro I'm also using an IDE, "Geany", I often use Netbeans or Eclipse, but this time i need to use that one and didn't tell me anything actually. It's been a while using it and i'm not pretty happy with it because it helps only in syntax. I appreciate your kindness but let this post be for what it is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Variable cannot be a number so here is the fixed code..**

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var x =  $(".header").height();
        $(".content").css ('margin-top', x);
    });
```

```css
 body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    background: #6396bc;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
.content {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><a href="#">Web</a></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">

        <div class="content">


    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var l = $(".header").height() + "px";
    $(".content").css ('margin-top', l);
    });
```

```css
        body {
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .container {
            width: 70%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .header {
            background: #6396bc;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            position: fixed;
        }
        .content {
            margin-top: 200px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="#">Web</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">

    <div class="content">


        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables names must start with letter or underscore or dollar sign.

Refer to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or
>   dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9).
>   Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters
>   "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z"
>   (lowercase).

please try this code

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var one = $(".header").height() + "px";
        $(".content").css ('margin-top', one);
    });
```

```css
 body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    background: #6396bc;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
.content {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><a href="#">Web</a></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">

        <div class="content">


    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.
</p>
</div>
</div>
```