# Typescript allows to create a class field name by starting with number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, language-features

Why typescript allows class field name in number

```
 1: number = 1;
 2: number = 2;
```

As per this discussion [Why can't variable names start with numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers) We can't create a class field name starting with number(even `JavaScript` also does not allow, if we define a variable name is starting with number). But in typescript we can create a class field name starting with number(whatever). Why? and it's a bug in `typescript`?.

### Reference

[image]

Comment: it doesn't, I'm not sure how you get that working? in the playground at least it doesn't https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%201%3Anumber%20%3D%201%3B

Comment: It does not accept inside the method. Am asking about when you declare the variable globally.

Comment: Even then it does not work. Provide a complete verifiable example.

Comment: @toskv and Murat I have attached the reference. Could you please explain for the down vote.

Comment: Those are not variables but class fields.

Comment: I am not understanding with variable name and class filed name in typescript :( . HMM!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those definitions of `1` and `2` aren't variable definitions, you're defining class members, which is totally fine to name them by a number.

But remember you can't access them by `this.1` you have to use `this[1]`.

In Javascript object properties can be named by a number (which is for example what the implementation of `Array` is doing), because (as @zerkms statet in the comments) they're implicitly converted into strings.

Comment: For more reading material https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Comment: "In Javascript object properties can be named by a number" --- JS object properties are strings. They are implicitly converted.

Comment: But I don't know why they are voting down for this question

Comment: @zerkms you're correct they're converted to strings. Added it to my answer.

Comment: @cyrix class member means method also a class member. but why method does not accept it.?

Comment: You can also use a number for a class method name: `1() {
    return 2;
  }`, typescript won't complain about it.

Comment: But I can't use it dude

Comment: Sure you can with `this[1]()`. But anyways don't name your class members and object properties by a `number` it's bad practise, unless you have a really really good reason to do so.