# Why am I getting 'is not a valid digit in integer literal' error while naming Swift enum case?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, enumeration

I'm trying to create an enum with running distances, but `Swift` is not letting me name the `enum` case with in this format `5K`. I get an error saying `'K' is not a valid digit in integer literal`. Here is my code: [image: code]

Comment: Please post the code as snippet, not as screenshot.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342152/why-cant-variable-names-start-with-numbers

Comment: @J.Doe seems to be the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identifiers and hence type properties/enum cases cannot start with numbers. You need to change the naming convention for your enum.

```
enum RaceType: String {
    case fiveK = "5K"
    case tenK = "10K"
    case marathon
}
```

Comment: It's not obvious that enum cases have anything to do with variables. Use *identifiers* to cover all those cases without implying a stronger relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

As a cheat you could use emojis like ５ or  as the starting letter.